# Merging similar xml files using python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to merge two similar xml files using python.

file1.xml:

```
<data>
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>value1</c>
      <d>value2</d>
    </b>
    <e>
      <f>value3</f>
      <g>value4</g>
    </e>
  </a>
</data>
```

file2.xml

```
<data>
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>value5</c>
      <d>value6</d>
    </b>
    <e>
      <f>value7</f>
      <g>value8</g>
    </e>
  </a>
</data>
```

Desired Output (file3.xml). Combine all the child for repeated b element but not combine the repeated e element.

```
<data>
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>value1</c>
      <d>value2</d>
      <c>value5</c>
      <d>value6</d>
    </b>
    <e>
      <f>value3</f>
      <g>value4</g>
    </e>
    <e>
      <f>value7</f>
      <g>value8</g>
    </e>
  </a>
</data>
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! Stack Overflow, unlike other discussion forums, is a **question-and-answer** site. Readers, such as yourself, ask questions and other readers attempt to answer them. Your post is missing the essential element of a successful [SO] post: a question! What, precisely, is your question?

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, I convert XMLs to a Python dict and merge manually dictionaries. After I re-convert dict to XML. Like that (Tested with Python 2.7):

```
import xmltodict
import collections


def merge_dict(d, u):
    """ 
        Merge two dictionaries. Manage nested dictionary and multiple values with same key.
        Return merged dict 
    """
    for k, v in u.items():
        if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
            d[k] = merge_dict(d.get(k, {}), v)
        else:
            # No more nested
            if k in d:
                # Manage multiple values with same name
                if not isinstance(d[k], list):
                    # if not a list create one
                    d[k] = [d[k]]
                d[k].append(v)
            else:
                # Single value
                d[k] = v
    return d


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Open input files
    with open("file1.xml", "r") as file1_xml, open("file2.xml", "r") as file2_xml:
        # Convert xml to dictionary
        file1_dict = xmltodict.parse(file1_xml.read())
        file2_dict = xmltodict.parse(file2_xml.read())

        # Merge dictionaries with special function
        file3_dict = merge_dict(file1_dict, file2_dict)

        # Open output file
        with open("file3.xml", "w") as file3_xml:
            file3_xml.write(xmltodict.unparse(file3_dict))
```

I use an `xmltodict` module for the conversion part. To install it use `pip install xmltodict`

Comment: Thanks, a lot for the answer. This is working but not quite the result i want. For example, this is merging all the duplicate elements. I don't want to merge element 'e' as in the above desired output file.

Comment: Yes I see but it's hard because I have not criteria for not merging all duplicate elements. How I can know which element I can merge (`b`) or not merge (`e`) ?